# Is Math an object or a class?

Tags: javascript, math

Every JavaScript reference I've seen, consider Math as a built-in object. So why isn't it a class in JavaScript as it is in most other programming languages?

Comment: _why isn't it a class in JavaScript as it is in most other programming languages_ This is quite ambiguous. In any case, I'm pretty confident it's a design choice, there is no official specification, as far as I know, that **motivates** why it is **not** a class and has not a constructor. My personal guess is that a constructor for that case specifically would be useless due to the nature of mathematical operations. As far as I can recall, though, it's **not** the only case where Math is not a class, or at least, let me correct myself, where Math **hasn't a constructor**.

Comment: @briosheje _it's a design choice, there is no official specification_, maybe that's the point. thank you.

Comment: I personally think Quentin's answer below is actually the correct answer. The above is just my own guess. The official MDN specification is there since 1997 and there is no mention about why it's in this way, they just mention that it's an object that has no constructor and can't be invoked with .call. Once again, though, it makes sense, I would've designed that in the same exact way. You can read more here: https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.8

Comment: Compare `Math.PI` vs `new Math().PI`. Since *class* would require the latter, I doubt there is a single benefit from the client's point of view. There are no benefits for the runtime, either.

Comment: @WiktorZychla Classes could have static properties and methods. if we say Math is a class, it wouldn't necessarily mean that we need the `new` keyword

Comment: @HITMAN: remember there are no *classes* in Javascript's runtime. Before ES6 stanctioned the syntactic sugar over `class` keyword (which technically is still a function), to most people *a class* would mean *a constructor function called with `new`*. As soon as static properties are introduced, it's just (an object* (despite technically it can be a function).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In most programming languages `Math` isn't a class but for the sake of argument, let's compare JavaScript to Java.

In Java, Math is a static class. It can't be instantiated. `new Math` doesn't make sense.

In JavaScript, a class is just a function that is designed to be called with the `new` operator and there is no such thing as a static class.

Since `Math` isn't designed to be instantiated and can't be called as a function, there's no reason to make it a function (or a class). It is just a thing designed to collect a bunch of properties together … and that is the basic definition of an object in JavaScript.

Comment: This would probably be the correct answer. just one thing, you said _In JavaScript, a class is just a function that is designed to be called with the new operator and there is no such thing as a static class. _ but ES6 classes allow making normal classes (like other languages) with static properties and methods, so it is possible to implement Math as a class.

Comment: @HITMAN — Not when `Math` was introduced though.

Comment: @HITMAN Well if we want to get technical about it, ES6 Classes are syntactic sugar on top of prototypal inheritance, not actual classes.

Comment: When you said " Not when Math was introduced though " . Did you mean that : when Math was introduced in JavaScript . ES6 was not released yet ( that is why ES6 was not used to Write the code of Math in JavaScript ) ? ( because the english is not my native language so I want to make sure that I understand you totally right  ) @Quentin

Answer (score 1):

Math is an Object, all the methods and properties of the Math object are static and can be used by calling Math as an object without creating it. It is not a constructor.

Comment: Well in other programming languages, Math is considered a class containing static properties and methods. my question is why JavaScript is different here?

Comment: This doesn't answer to the original question which is **why** it's designed in this way.

Comment: Because in Javascript the closest thing to a 'class containing static properties' is probably just a plain old javascript object?